# Which verb form to use after "limits itself to"?

Tags: gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

I am wondering about the correct verb form to use here:

> This article limits itself to **consider**...

or

> This article limits itself to **considering**...

For this example both sound dubious to me (possibly because of the presence of 'to'), and those I have asked are also unsure, including a native English speaker.

And what about the passive counterpart:

> This article is limited to **consider**...

> This article is limited to **considering**...

Comment: Can you please provide a full sentence as an example

Comment: @dubious For example: "This article limits itself to consider statistics from the UK and not from other countries."

Comment: I'm certain it should be _considering_ in both cases, but I don't have time to explain why with a formal answer. For what it's worth, I'm a native English speaker.

Comment: From [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=limited+to+make%2Climited+to+making&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) "limited to making" is 4 times more frequent than "limited to make".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is less problematic to investigate verbs other than 'consider', or to change the subject to reference a sentient agent:

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/limit) gives examples only of the form

> [limit] to control something so that it is not more than a particular
> amount, number, or level:
>
> limit something to something
>
> - *I've been asked to limit my speech to ten minutes maximum.*
>
> [limit] to control the amount of something or the type of thing that a
> person or organization can have:
>
> limit somebody to something
>
> - *Having so little money to spend on a car does limit you to an older used model.*
> - *The city's economy limits the poor to menial service jobs.*
>
> limit yourself to something
>
> - *Older investors do not have to limit themselves to corporate bonds.* that is, [limit] + [DO] + [to] + [{prototypical} noun group].

However, a Google search for "limited themselves to" provides many (showing all the relevant results in the first 40 hits) additional examples of the form [limit] + [DO] + [verbal ing-group]:

> - *[They] ... have limited themselves to showing how that belief was plausible.*
> - *... they limited themselves to considering land that was ...*
> - *The texts written about the Restoration have almost always limited themselves to reproducing the legitimising discourses ....*
> - *The answers limited themselves to suggesting further exploration ....*
> - *... the majority of the Muslims today have limited themselves to repeating the words ....*
> - *... applicants have limited themselves to adding to the file various Parliamentary documents ....*
> - *... who have limited themselves to denouncing or expressing opinions critical of those [in] public office.*
> - *... some ... banks including South Africa and India limited themselves to buying government debt ...*
> - *... limited themselves to referring to the relevant provisions of the domestic law ...*

There are also just two examples of the form [limit] + [to] + [bare infinitive] in the first 100 hits:

> - *The Icelandic authorities have not clarified whether the above conditions will be met under the Tonnage Tax Act, but limited
>   themselves to repeat the conditions set out in Article 3 of the
>   Tonnage Tax Act.*
> - *I have reported all those issues to the developers and they limited themselves to provide detached scripts to locally fix the problems*
>   ...

These don't sound too outlandish, though none of CD, OALD, Collins, AHD, Macmillan, RHK Webster's and M-W give examples of this form.

The present participle is certainly acceptable where it makes sense; the to-infinitive ***is*** sometimes found used, even in respectable-looking documents, but is far less common and may sound unnatural to some (even where it otherwise makes sense).

Answer (score 2):

They have different meanings:

> This article limits itself to consider...

= This article limits itself *in order* to consider...

This gives the purpose of limiting.

> This article limits itself to considering...

= This article limits itself to the consideration of...

This gives the bounds of the verb "to limit".

Comment: That's an interesting consideration, thank you! I was after the second meaning, so I will make sure to use that.

Answer (score 0):

The first examples sound unnatural. An article doesn't have agency and so can't really "*limit itself*".

For the passive form, you could say:

- This article considers statistics from the UK and not from other countries.
- This article only considers statistics from the UK.
- This article is limited to statistics from the UK and not from other countries.

Comment: Thanks! I understand of course that my artificial example might not be the most natural way to say it, but my question is specifically about this particular grammar issue. At least my second example in passive form should be valid, right? And at least one of those two options should be correct, so which one would it be?

Comment: "The article" does have agency. "The article limits itself" = the author of the article limits himself / the scope of the article. See https://www.google.com/search?q="the%20article%20limits%20itself"&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2004,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en